# VS Code error when importing Django module

Tags: python, django, macos, visual-studio-code

I'm working on a web app and I use Django as framework.
I'm using VS Code on a macOS.

I get an error when I try to import some Django module. This is a screenshot of my code in error.

[image: Image of my code in error]

The error message is the following:

> [pylint] E0401:Unable to import 'django.conf.urls'

Answer (score 84):

I too was facing this error while working with Python virtual environments. In my case, it was happening because I have installed Django on my virtual environment and my base environment didn't contain any module named Django.

Base(Global) environment
[image: No module named Django in my global enviroment]

and when I use the same command inside my virtual environment (**myDjangoEnv**)
[image]

**Fix:**

1. Now what I understood is that pylint uses the python interpreter to analyze our code and mark the error while we write the code.
2. Since I have three python environments in my system, hence three different python interpreters are available to my VS Code.

So if VS code uses the Python interpreter from the base environment, it will not recognize the Django module (import Error). Therefore, you are required to change the Python interpreter to the one present in your virtual environment.

It sounds complicated but it is pretty simple:

1. *Click on the bottom left of the screen to change python interpreter.* [image: changing python interpreter]
2. *Select from the list of available Python interpreters. Make sure you select the appropriate interpreter with respect to the current project.* [image]

Comment: Note that the pythonPath setting will be stored in your workspace, which is nice.

Comment: This is great. I was first a bit confused by the pictures. If this happens to anyone, read the instructions again carefully. It does work!

Comment: You are my hero.

Comment: You are my hero

Comment: You are my ....

Answer (score 14):

### Follow steps mentioned in the image. For details, or if that doesn't work, read further!!!

[image]

If you can't see your interpreter (installed in the virtual environment) listed in the drop-down list OR selecting interpreters listed don't rectify the error.

Then, you have to give the path of your interpreter (installed in venv) to vs code. Because you might have installed Django only in your venv. Happens when you don't use anaconda to create venv.

Steps to rectify-

1. To check the path, activate venv and type `which python` in terminal, this will give path. Copy the path.
2. Click interpreter on lower left, to pull drop-down, as shown in pic above.
3. Click enter the interpreter path.
4. Paste path copied.

This will assign the right interpreter and rectify the error.

Comment: this worked for me! i think it's important people understand that you can accidentally override your workspace setting in `.vscode/settings.json` so make sure if you've got one set to remove it before you follow the steps above.

Comment: `'which' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Answer (score 9):

1. Locate your project's virtual environment. In my case, I am working on a Django project and my virtual environment is located on the path below:

   ```
   C:/Users/abc/Desktop/Virutal36/myLab/Scripts/python.exe
   ```
2. Copy the address of your virtual environment.
3. On VS Code, Select File > Preferences> Settings to open your User Settings (or use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> shortcut).
4. Create or modify an entry for python.pythonPath with the full path to your virtual environment and you will be good to go. In my case it is:

   ```
   C:/Users/abc/Desktop/Virutal36/myLab01/Scripts/python.exe
   ```

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_manually-specify-an-interpreter

Comment: It works for me. In my case Visual Studio Code cannot recognize my virtual environment through interpreter. Manual settings saves me.

Comment: I had no clue that virtual env installed Python.

Answer (score 5):

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>
2. Type *Python:select interpreter*
   Now we will get:

   [image]
3. Choose *Enter interpreter path*:
   [image]
4. Select `Find...`
   Then
   [image]

Answer (score 3):

Check correct django version is properly installed and active?

In the active environment, calling this code in python interpreter shouldn't have errors. 
 
`from django.conf.urls import url`

Check the VS studio python environment
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments

Comment: Django is correctly installed, I think the issue could come from the pythonpath but I don't know where this option is set.

Comment: Thanks, man! I choose my project venv from the list and it worked.  :)

Answer (score 3):

You need to select the right **environment**. So, go to **view** in tool bar, then select **command pallet(ctrl+shift+p)**, then type "**python:select interpreter**", then select the **right virtual environment where you start you project**.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I solved it using the Select Interpreter option from VS Code's Command Palette (Shift + Command + P).

I chose the Python interpreter option which corresponds with the folder in which my virtual environment was and it solved the issue immediately.

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a virtual environment (mkvirtualenv)? In that case you need to make sure you install django and pylint etc., within your virtual environment too, using the following commands.

1. workon [yourEnvName]
2. pip install pylint
3. pip install django
4. pip install djangorestframework

and so on...for all the modules you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PEMwV.png)

Choosing a global environment helped me to recover this issue

Answer (score 0):

First check the requirements that you install djangorestframework, second if you work on virtual envs maybe the pylint that you use not check in your virtual env so you can install in local the package.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I opened the nested folder of my Django project. So, Django couldn't find the modules of `venv`.

Just mentioning, I thought it might be helpful to someone.