# getting problem in importing libraries in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm getting this error
even tho I have installed pylint in the environment it still showing this error

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Seeing all the red on the left and the underlined `firstpage` there seems to be something wrong with your project setup.

Comment: That was just a silly mistake! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48270385/vs-code-error-when-importing-django-module

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VS Code error when importing Django module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48270385/vs-code-error-when-importing-django-module)

Comment: Yes I found that earlier yesterday , thank you

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with django and firstpage, not pylint. Install them in the same way you installed pylint.

Comment: thank you for replying , but it didn't solve my problem. however i found the solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48270385/vs-code-error-when-importing-django-module