# How to define a virtual environment in vs-code

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code

I am a noob to vs-code (starting using it yesterday and I like it)

I have a minor irritation. I am working on a django project and I'm using a virtualenv with virtualenvwrapper. The problem that I have is that (for example) in the line

```
from django.shortcuts import render
```

the linter says

> Unable to import 'django.shortcuts'pylint(import-error)

My virtualenvs are in the directory *~/Envs* and

```
ls -l Envs
```

returns

```
drwxr-xr-x 4 jeff jeff 4096 Jun 18 14:46 django
-rwxr-xr-x 1 jeff jeff  135 Jun 18 15:23 get_env_details
-rw-r--r-- 1 jeff jeff   96 Jun 18 15:23 initialize
-rw-r--r-- 1 jeff jeff   73 Jun 18 15:23 postactivate
-rw-r--r-- 1 jeff jeff   75 Jun 18 15:23 postdeactivate
-rwxr-xr-x 1 jeff jeff   66 Jun 18 15:23 postmkproject
-rw-r--r-- 1 jeff jeff   73 Jun 18 15:23 postmkvirtualenv
-rwxr-xr-x 1 jeff jeff  110 Jun 18 15:23 postrmvirtualenv
-rwxr-xr-x 1 jeff jeff   99 Jun 18 15:23 preactivate
-rw-r--r-- 1 jeff jeff   76 Jun 18 15:23 predeactivate
-rwxr-xr-x 1 jeff jeff   91 Jun 18 15:23 premkproject
-rwxr-xr-x 1 jeff jeff  130 Jun 18 15:23 premkvirtualenv
-rwxr-xr-x 1 jeff jeff  111 Jun 18 15:23 prermvirtualenv
drwxr-xr-x 4 jeff jeff 4096 Jun 18 15:26 wagtail
```

I am working in the venv *django*

I have tried setting the *Python: Venv Path* and/or *Python: Venv Folders* to *~/Envs* and *~/Envs/django*. I have restarted vs-code, but the problem persists

What should I do?

Comment: you are using wrong python directory  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48270385/vs-code-error-when-importing-django-module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you tried like this :
To select a specific environment, use the Python: Select Interpreter command from the Command Palette (Ctrl+Shift+P).

[image]

You can switch environments at any time; switching environments helps you test different parts of your project with different interpreters or library versions as needed.

The Python: Select Interpreter command displays a list of available global environments, conda environments, and virtual environments. (See the Where the extension looks for environments section for details, including the distinctions between these types of environments.) The following image, for example, shows several Anaconda and CPython installations along with a conda environment and a virtual environment (env) that's located within the workspace folder:

[image]

sources:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the Python Interpreter to the option with `venv`.
[image]